# SQLAlchemy: Convert column value back and forth between internal and database format

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, data-conversion

In my database, I have some columns where data is stored in some weird format. Since the database is used by other code, too, I cannot change the data format.

For example, one of the weird formats is that a time value is represented as a string like `23:42:30`. I would like to have some magic that allows me to always use `datetime.time` objects on the python side.

A very simple solution would be something like:

```
col_raw = Column('col', String(7))

@property
def col(self):
    return datetime.strptime(self.col_raw, '%H:%M:%S').time()
@col.setter
def colself, t):
    self.col_raw = t.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

However, this only solves the problem for reading and writing data. Stuff like this would not be possible:

```
Table.query.filter(Table.col == time(23,42,30))
```

Another way would be to use the [hybrid extension](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html). That way, querying would be possible, but if I see it correctly, writing wouldn't. Besides, it requires writing coding everything twice, once in python code and once in SQL code. (Additional problem: I'm not sure if the conversion can be written using SQL code only.)

Is there really no way that combines both? Such as I define two functions, let's say `python2sql` and `sql2python`, which SQLAlchemy uses to transparently convert the values from python object to string and the back?  I know that this would make some queries impossible, such as `between` or `like` or sums and the like, but that's okay.

Please keep in mind that the time thing is only example one of the cases where I need to convert data; so please try to keep the replies generic.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use a [type decorator](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/custom_types.html#augmenting-existing-types) that handles converting to and from the custom format.  Use this type rather than `String` when defining your column.

```
class MyTime(TypeDecorator):
    impl = String

    def __init__(self, length=None, format='%H:%M:%S', **kwargs)
        super().__init__(length, **kwargs)
        self.format = format

    def process_literal_param(self, value, dialect):
        # allow passing string or time to column
        if isinstance(value, basestring):  # use str instead on py3
            value = datetime.strptime(value, self.format).time()

        # convert python time to sql string
        return value.strftime(self.format) if value is not None else None

    process_bind_param = process_literal_param

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        # convert sql string to python time
        return datetime.strptime(value, self.format).time() if value is not None else None

# in your model
class MyModel(Base):
    time = Column(MyTime(length=7))
```