# How can I select * from table, but cast one or more of the columns to a different datatype using ORM (Sqlalchemy)

Tags: oracle, sqlalchemy, orm, fastapi, python-oracledb

I have this multiple orm model for fastapi endpoint like this:

```
@mapper_registry.mapped
@dataclass
class Department:
    __tablename__ = "department"
     __sa_dataclass_metadata_key__ = "sa"

    id: float = field(
        init=False, metadata={"sa": Column(NUMBER(15, 0, False), primary_key=True)})
    label: str = field(metadata={"sa": Column(VARCHAR(255), nullable=False)})
    active: str = field(
        metadata={"sa": Column(CHAR(1), nullable=False, server_default=text("'Y' "))})
    sort_order: Optional[float] = field(
        default=None, metadata={"sa": Column(NUMBER(4, 0, False))})
    entry_key: Optional[str] = field(
        default=None, metadata={"sa": Column(VARCHAR(255))})
    external_key: Optional[str] = field(
        default=None, metadata={"sa": Column(VARCHAR(255), server_default=text("null"))})
  date_created: datetime = field(metadata={"sa": Column(TIMESTAMP(True), nullable=False)})
 date_modified: datetime = field(metadata={"sa": Column(TIMESTAMP(True), nullable=False)})
```

And also pydantic model equivalent.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
class DepartmentResponse(BaseModel):
    id: float
    label: str
    active: str
    date_created: datetime
    date_modified: datetime
```

I am using python oracledb. The original issue is that Fetching timestamp with time zone (date_modified and date_created) in this case raises error ORA-01805: possible error in date/time operation https://github.com/oracle/python-oracledb/issues/20. The error have to do with internal implementation of oracle timestamp with timezone.

Basically, I am trying to explore the workaround of casting date_created and date_modified to string before fetching.

This is just a simple example. I have tables with nested object (table) and large number of columns, so I don't want to call them one by one just to solve this timestamp fetching issues and I am trying to avoid multiple join statements as much as possible (The major reason I am using sqlalchemy/orm in the first place)

Maybe my question should have been to pre-cast these timestamp with timezone fields before fetching them with the reset of the fields. casting to timestamp to string (func.to_char) during fetch works for the timestamp fields.

Or largely a way to solve the timestamp fetching error.

Comment: Note that the answer to which you link selects all the columns of the table, *plus* one containing the result of the cast.  It does not substitute the result of the cast for the column on which it is based.

Comment: Note also that SQLAlchemy is not only or even primarily an ORM system.  It does provide an ORM subsystem, but your example code does not appear to be using that.  Whether you are in fact performing the DB access via the ORM makes a big difference to how you might reasonably proceed with something like this.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3180375/2144390

Comment: @snakecharmerb, I just fixed the link. Basically, I want to be able to select all the columns from a table excluding the column that I want to reformat or cast. 
Say for example and SQLalchemy ORM equivalent of
Select COLUMN1, COLUMN3... COLUMN N, CAST(COLUMN2 as INT)

Comment: @JohnBollinger thank you for your response, unlike the link provided, I want to be able to substitute the result of the  cast from base select

Comment: @Isaac, you did not fix the link.  You *broke* the fix already performed by others, completely losing the URL in the process.  Not that the link was directly relevant, of course, inasmuch as what you should have been taking from it is that SQL itself does not support what you describe.  And I think it's moot, because if you are accessing the table via the ORM then you are not writing SQL statements.  But you *are* explicitly mapping all the columns of the table, except possibly any that you don't care about accessing via the table's models.

Comment: I am using the ORM in this case and it does not make sense to call each of the columns individually. I need all the columns and calling them together is better for my use case

Comment: @JohnBollinger, sorry about messing with the link. I guess it has been replaced now... 
I did not get your point about mapping the columns

Comment: @Isaac, you say that you are using the SQLAlchemy ORM subsystem, but what you describe does not sound like that at all.  How about this: edit the question to present the model class you are mapping to the table in question.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, I just reedit with more details of the root cause and my thinking process. I hope I did not complicate things more. thanks

Comment: Ok, great.  Now, you were talking about selecting all the columns of the underlying table, but when you use the ORM to access the table, *it* chooses how to perform the accesses.  Moreover, to the best of my knowledge, when you use SQLAlchemy's declarative mapping style (as you are doing) only those attributes for which you declare mappings will be mapped to database columns, so you will need to do that for every column you care about. In that sense, "I don't want to call them one by one" is moot. [...]

Answer (score 0):

> Basically, I am trying to explore the workaround of casting date_created and date_modified to string before fetching. Say for example:
>
> ```
> Select COLUMN1, COLUMN3... COLUMN N, CAST(COLUMN2 as INT)
> ```

You need to understand that when you use an ORM, it is for the most part the ORM that writes queries.  That is in fact one of the major selling points.  To accomplish what you describe, you need to

1. Avoid mapping `COLUMN2` itself to your model class for its table.  This will mean, of course, that you cannot set values for that column via the ORM, but that should be fine if you're relying on triggers in the DB to maintain the columns in question.
2. Supposing that you need that column's data at all, instruct your ORM to map the expression `CAST(COLUMN2 as INT)` to an attribute of your model class instances.

Since you're using SQLAlchemy's declarative mapping style, you should get only those mappings you declare, so (1) should be easy.

SQLAlchemy's docs, though voluminous, are a little opaque on how you would accomplish (2), but probably it would be by using a [`column_property()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html#using-column-property) in place of a `Column()` / `mapped_column()`.  You may even be able to specify the SQL expression as a plain Python string, something like:

```
  date_created: int = column_property('CAST(date_created as INT)')
```

HOWEVER, I'm not following how any of what you show in the question lines up with ...

> I have tables with nested object (table) and large number of columns, so I don't want to call them one by one just to solve this timestamp fetching issues

To solve this at the Python / SQL interface, you absolutely need to individually map (at least) every column you want to interact with on the Python side, and the mapping example you show seems to indicate that you already recognize and are trying to do that.

Comment: Thank you for your responses.  I need the date_created and date_modified data. I was able to map the CAST operation to an attribute in the class instance as you suggested. column_property does not really work. But hybrid_property does work. 
The problem now is that db.query(Department).all() for instance still calls the original  date_created giving the same error. How do you suggest I exclude the original date_created from the query? I tried using options(defer(...)), since the original column is not fetched, the  formatted column cannot be called.

Comment: @Isaac, to the best of my knowledge, `hybrid_property` does not serve your purposes because it depends on you mapping the `created_date` and `updated_date` columns themselves in order to define corresponding integer versions.  Avoiding that is (literally, see above) the #1 thing you must avoid doing.

Comment: @Isaac, I don't know what it means that "column_property does not really work", but if you cannot figure out how to *make* it work -- and that depends on too many factors for me to solve for you -- then [using a plain descriptor](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html#using-a-plain-descriptor) is likely your last resort within SQLAlchemy.

Comment: (cc: @Isaac ) - FWIW, I am unable to reproduce an error reading a TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE column using vanilla SQLAlchemy and oracledb in thin mode. [This code](https://gist.github.com/gordthompson/737596bbd70a0094e1daf281d47b213e) works for me, and DBeaver shows the DATE_CREATED column as `2024-02-23 07:41:10.915 -0700`.

Comment: @GordThompson, yes. it is possible to be able to read TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE without the error when ORA_TZFILE is the same on both server and client. This simple solution should have been to upgrade the database itself to a latest oracle release but that is not an option since this is a very a huge legacy system with other dependencies. I cannot change the database.

Comment: @JohnBollinger According to the documentation example; fullname = column_property(firstname + " " + lastname). This required that the date_created for example be defined before it can be "changed". This take me back to the same issue as the Timestamp with time zone columns will still needs to be prefetch on query call. same with property and hybrid_property

Comment: @Isaac - Have you tried using `engine = create_engine(connection_url, thick_mode=True)` to see if it makes any difference?

Comment: @Isaac, using expressions involving `Column` objects is *one alternative* for `column_property()`.  The docs are not entirely forthcoming, but there is every reason to think that others are possible.  In particular, inasmuch as SQLAlchemy supports SQL literals in other places, either as raw strings or as `literal()`s, I am inclined to think (but do not know for certain) that that is an option for `column_property()`.  The same is not true for `hybrid_property()`, as I understand that, because the point of that approach is to have both SQL and Python semantics.

Comment: @Isaac - nvm re: thick mode, I just saw [this](https://github.com/oracle/python-oracledb/issues/20#issuecomment-1959109483).

Comment: Thanks to @JohnBollinger for the suggested solution and pointing to that part of sqlalchemy documentation. 
Looking closely to sqlalchemy documentation, I was able to figure out a solution credit also to this trend: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28143557/sqlalchemy-convert-column-value-back-and-forth-between-internal-and-database-fo

Comment: I created a custom TIMESTAMP

    import sqlalchemy.types as types
    from sqlalchemy import  func
    class MyTimestamp(types.TypeDecorator):
        impl = types.TIMESTAMP
        cache_ok = True
        
        def column_expression(self, col):
            print("column_expression: ", col)
            return func.to_char(col,  'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')

Comment: This custom function does the converting prefetching the data in the database. Then my sqlalchemy model is like this:

     date_created: datetime = field(
            metadata={"sa": Column(MyTimestamp, nullable=False)})

My queries now work as expected.

Comment: @JohnBollinger you may want to look at it and add it to your solution for others to see. I lost the permission to post answers :). Thank you for your help on this